# Badge not showing in VUE loaded from CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a VUE page where I try to render a badge. It shows the text but only white. I tried also with bootstrap badges with the same results.

This is the code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body role="document">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="start">
                <h2>b-badge: <b-badge variant="primary">b-badge</b-badge> {{foo}} </h2>
                class: <span class="badge">span</span>
        </div><!-- start -->
    </div>
    <script src="/js/vue/start.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript with VUE code loaded from start.js before.

```
var start = new Vue({
    el: '#start'
    ,
    data: {
        foo: "bar"
    }
});
```

VUE loads because I spot the result of the *foo* variable in the page. But the badge will only show white text no matter what class I try to load. Both with bootstrap and bootstrap-vue.

This is what is rendered:

[image: badge as rendered as white text]

If I select the text I can see there is a white text where the badge should be.

I tried many other VUE code and everything works fine including a navbar. I also tried to import the Badger but I can't manage to do that. I only get that error:

```
"import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"
```

My guess is as I am using CDN loaded VUE I don't need to do the import. Also I searched if I have to load the Badge javascript or CSS from another link at the header but I can't find it anywhere.

Any hints ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue it with the version of Bootstrap you're importing.
The following line

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

will import the latest version of Bootstrap, which is Bootstrap 5, released a couple of weeks ago.

While BootstrapVue is currently built for Bootstrap 4.5.3.

So if you change the import to specifically import version `4.5.3`, it should work correctly.

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#start",
  data() {
    return {
      foo: "bar"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="start">
  <h2>b-badge:
    <b-badge variant="primary">b-badge</b-badge> {{ foo }} </h2>
  class: <span class="badge">span</span>
</div>
```